# ErrorListPlot shows only errorbars but not the data points.

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-8, wolframalpha

I have been using the command `ErrorListPlot` in almost all of my mathematica scripts. However, recently I have seen that after execution of my mathematica script, the function `ErrorListPlot` shows red colored (while all executed functions are black colored upon execution).
I am importing the package by ``` Needs[ErrorBarPlots``] ```, which is called in the beginning of the script. 
Apart from the red color of the function  `ErrorListPlot`, what is bothering me is that the plot shows error bars but not the data points. Initially, it used to show the data points as well as the error bars.

Comment: Please post the code of a minimal example of the problem.

Comment: try why the coloring from the help menu